# Angular - The declaration was marked as deprecated for subscribe

Tags: angular

In Angular-13, I am implementing reactive form. I have this code in the component:

```
createForm() {
  this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
    userName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(80)])
  })
}

login(){
  this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(res=>{
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }, error=>{
    console.log(error);
    this.toastr.error(error.error);
  })
}
```

But I got this error and subscribe is crossed:

> The declaration was marked as deprecated

How do I get it resolve?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an observer as argument.

```
const observer = {
  next: x => console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x),
  error: err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification'),
};
```

In your case since you only need to react to next and error notifications, it would be like this.

```
login(){
  this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe({
    next: (res) => this.router.navigateByUrl('/'), 
    error: (error) => {
      console.log(error);
      this.toastr.error(error.error);
    }
  })
}
```

cheers